# How Can I Access The Primary Key (from the database) In A Template?

Tags: python, django

In my project, I want to display a category page, that lists all of the products in a specific category. Each of the listings on the category page will link the visitor to that specific product.

The product view is working properly. Products are accessed with the url: /prod/999 where 999 is the django created record number.

For the category page, I have the data and I'm working on my template. I can access the product name, description etc.. in the template but in creating the link to the product detail page, I need that product record. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be passed to the template.

How do I pass the record number "pk" to my template?

Here's my view code:

```
from get_data.models import ShareASale_Data, CategorySummed
```

class CategoryView(generic.ListView):

```
model = ShareASale_Data
template_name = 'summary_page/category.html'
context_object_name="the_records"
paginate_by = 10

def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):

    # First Get the Actual Category from the Category db.
    cat_summed = CategorySummed.objects.get(category_url = self.kwargs['s_cat']) 

    # Use the category from the previous line to fetch the product records
    return ShareASale_Data.objects.filter(merch_category = cat_summed.category )
```

not much to the template so far. This is where I'm trying to access the pk:

```
{% for x in the_records  %}
  <h3><a href='/prod/'{{x.id}}>{{x.name}}</a></h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The pk is an attribute of an object, which in turn is one of the items in the query set you are presumably iterating through in your template. If you are having trouble with this you should show the template.

Comment: not much to the template so far. This is where I'm trying to access the pk:

{% for x in the_records  %}
      <h3><a href='/prod/'{{x.id}}>{{x.name}}</a></h3>
    {% endfor %}

Comment: I would probably do this by setting up a `get_absolute_url` method on the model class and using `{% url some_model_instance %}` rather than referring to the PK at all - see the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Answer (score 3):

You've put the template variable outside the closing quote in the href attribute, so it won't be used in the link by the browser. Put it inside.

```
<a href='/prod/{{x.id}}'>{{x.name}}</a>
                       ^ here
```

But note that this isn't really how you should create links in templates; you should use the `url` tag. Assuming your detail URL is defined like this:

```
url(r'^prod/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='my_detail_view')
```

you would do:

```
<a href='{% url 'my_detail_view' id=x.id %}'>{{x.name}}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, yep, I didn't have id within the quotes (DUH!). Thanks for pointing me toward URL tag, as you can tell I'm a newbie just trying to get my first full project up and running. Thanks again!